# Copying & Pasting Certain Cells Between the Multiple Workbooks

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

Below code is run from "data.xlsx" excel workbook and should prompt user to open excel workbook file and Copy data from "data.xlsx" into user opened excel workbook.

```
Sub test()
    Dim ToSheet As Worksheet
    Dim FromBook As String
    Dim FromSheet As Worksheet
     '--------------------------------------------------------------------
    Set ToSheet = ActiveSheet
    FromBook = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel Files (*.xlsx), *.xlsx, All Files (*.*), *.*", 1, "Select Log File ")
    If FromBook = "False" Then Exit Sub
    Workbooks.Open FromBook
    Set FromSheet = ActiveSheet.Worksheets("Sheet1")
     '--------------------------------------------------------------------
     'Copy / Paste Data
   ToSheet.Activate
   DoColumnCopy "Apple", "Orange"
End Sub
'-------------------------------------------------------
'I need below code to work between the workbook, currently it 
'only works between the worksheet.

'Get data from FromColName and copy to ToColName
Sub DoColumnCopy(FromColName As String, ToColName As String)

    Dim rng As Range, rngCopy As Range, rng2 As Range

    Set rng = workbooks(1).Sheets("data").Rows(1).Find(What:=FromColName, LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                  LookAt:=xlWhole)
    If Not rng Is Nothing Then

        Set rngCopy = workbooks(1).Sheets("data").Range(rng).End(xlDown)

        Set rng2 = workbooks(2).Sheets("log").Rows(1).Find(What:=ToColName, LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                   LookAt:=xlWhole)

        If Not rng2 Is Nothing Then rngCopy.Copy rng2.Offset(1, 0)

    End If
End Sub
```

How can I fix this `workbooks(2).sheets...` part of the code so it knows the name of user opened workbook? or if there are multiple workbooks opened?

I welcome If you have better methods of doing this
Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to declare your object for the other workbook and assign to it. For example (UNTESTED)

```
Sub test()
    Dim thisWb As Workbook, destWb As Workbook
    Dim ToSheet As Worksheet, FromSheet As Worksheet
    Dim FromBook As String

    '~~> Current workbook and the sheet
    Set thisWb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ToSheet = thisWb.ActiveSheet

    FromBook = Application.GetOpenFilename( _
    "Excel Files (*.xlsx), *.xlsx, All Files (*.*), *.*", 1, "Select Log File ")
    If FromBook = "False" Then Exit Sub

    '~~> This is how you store it in an object and then use it
    Set destWb = Workbooks.Open(FromBook)
    Set FromSheet = destWb.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    '
    '~~> Rest of your code
    '
End Sub
```

Comment: First, thank you for being so proactive with your expertise :)
But for the `sub DoColumnCopy` how should I go about using the `thisWb` & `destWb`?  
Would `thisWb.Sheets("sheet1")` isn't doing it...

Comment: What are "Apples" and "Oranges" here? Values from some column? Are they picked up from some cell?

Comment: Apple & Orange is text string for `DoColumnCopy`, it searches for "Apple" in row A1, grabs the data in that column (current workbook) and searches for "orange" in row A1 in **sheet1 of user opened workbook** and paste the data.

Comment: So as per my code `Apple` would be in `thisWb` and `orange` in `destWb`?

Comment: Correct. I have tried `DoColumnCopy toSheet("Apple"), FromSheet("Orange")` but it errors...

Comment: Is your problem sorted?